# How to GROUP BY in SQL and then mark as 0,1

Tags: sql, group-by

I need to `GROUP BY item_id` and check if `user_id` in any of those matches a variable. If so, I want it to = 1, if not 0.

for example, imagine table like this:

```
item_id, user_id
1         1
1         3
2         4
2         1
2         7
2         3
3         4
3         6
4         8
4         1
5         3


IF (user_id = 3,1,0) AS match,
```

Want my Query to come back as

```
item_id, match
1        1 
2        1
3        0
4        0
5        1
```

Where "1" all occurrences of user_id 3 in an item_id group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the right aggregation function:

```
select item_id,
       max(case when user_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as hasmatch
from t
group by item_id
order by item_id
```

Comment: `case when something then 1 else 0 end` = `something`

Comment: @AndreKR . . . that simplification is not true in all databases.  The syntax in my answer is ANSI standard and supported by just about any database I can think of.

Comment: Ok, a quick look at the specs didn't come up with proof of the opposite, so to be safe I edited my answer.

Comment: When I try this, I get `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match
from ratings
group by item_id
order by item_id' at line 2`

Comment: That's probably because `MATCH` is a reserved word in MySQL. Try a different identifier or use backticks.

Answer (score 1):

In **MySQL**, *true* is 1 and *false* is 0, so you can just do:

```
SELECT item_id, MAX(user_id = 3) AS has_match
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```

You can even count the number of matches:

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(user_id = 3) AS matches
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```

`GROUP BY 1` is short for `GROUP BY item_id`, as `item_id` is the first select expression.

Comment: . . you should become familiar with SQLFiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com).  You can try out queries on different databases.  The `SUM`/`MAX` syntax does not work on Oracle, SQL Server, or Postgres.  The `GROUP BY 1` syntax is also not standard.  As far as I know, *true* and *false* are not defined by the standard and not generally defined in most databases.

Comment: @AndreKR The top one almost works to my needs.  I may go with this. Very simple.  Will try to implement and will get back.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

```
SELECT
    A.item_id, ISNULL(B.count, 0)
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT item_id 'item_id' FROM myTable) AS A
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT item_id, count(*) 'count' 
            FROM myTable WHERE user_id IN (3, 1, 0)
            GROUP BY item_id
        ) AS B
    ON A.item_id = B.item_id
```